# Nest API 401 Response Error using RestSharp c#

Tags: c#, restsharp, nest-api

I'm trying to get the JSON response for my devices/structures data from the Nest API. "https://developer-api.nest.com/"

I've been able to retrieve the data using Postman with the same url while only specifying the content-type and authorization headers. I essentially copied the code snippet from Postman into my program, but I'm receiving a 401 error upon running.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://developer-api.nest.com/");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Here's the response content:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#auth-error","message":"unauthorized","instance":"e0a35869-6726-4192-85d5-d31482b28269"}
```

Do I need to encode the access_token in some way?

Thanks for your responses.

Here's a sample of what the output should look like:

```
{
  "devices": {
    "thermostats": {
      "fbk1Kr983gWp-eN-V9pxnOcTsTatUX5X": {
        "humidity": 15,
        "locale": "en-US",
        "temperature_scale": "F",
        ...
```

Comment: do you have an output of what the API call looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

The Nest API's initial response is (most of the time) a redirect to their Firebase API server. I handled the redirect by adding the if statement below:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://developer-api.nest.com/");
client.FollowRedirects = false;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb) // 307
{
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri(initial_response.Headers[7].Value.ToString());
    response = client.Execute(request);               
}
```

Note that I set the FollowRedirects property to false. The second response content contains the expected JSON data.